# How do I scrape URL's from google search with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to loop through a csv. for each iteration, attach string "sherdog" to the value and google search that. From the results of each query, I want to copy the first URL that contains sherdog.com. And paste that url into the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Import CSV file and create DataFrame with columns 'name_a', 'url_a', 'name_b', 'url_b'
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/daneweickert/Downloads/Sherdog Links - UFC 285_ Jones vs Gane (1).csv')
print(df)

# Set up Chrome webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')  # to run the webdriver in headless mode
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

# Loop through each row of the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    name_a = row['name_a']
    
    # Google search for name_a + "sherdog"
    query = f"{name_a} sherdog"
    url_a = ''
    try:
        driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}")
        print(f"Search query: {query}")
        # Get the URL of the top search result from sherdog.com
        top_result = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.g div.r a[href^="https://www.sherdog.com/"]')
        #top_result = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[@href^="https://www.sherdog.com/"]')
        url_a = top_result.get_attribute('href')
        print(f"Top search result for {name_a}: {url_a}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error searching for {name_a}: {str(e)}")
    
    # Update the 'url_a' column for the current row
    df.at[index, 'url_a'] = url_a
    
    # Loop through each value of 'name_b' and attach the url from each search to 'url_b'
    for i in range(index, len(df)):
        name_b = df.at[i, 'name_b']
        query = f"{name_b} sherdog"
        url_b = ''
        try:
            driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}")
            print(f"Search query: {query}")
            # Get the URL of the top search result from sherdog.com
            top_result = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.g div.r a[href^="https://www.sherdog.com/"]')
            #top_result = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[@href^="https://www.sherdog.com/"]')
            url_b = top_result.get_attribute('href')
            print(f"Top search result for {name_b}: {url_b}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error searching for {name_b}: {str(e)}")
        
        # Update the 'url_b' column for the current row
        df.at[i, 'url_b'] = url_b
    
# Close the Chrome webdriver
driver.quit()

print(df)
```

Comment: And what does your code do that you don't like?  Note that space is not a valid character in a URL.  You should be doing `f"{name_a}+sherdog"`.  And if you want the results limited to sherdog.com, you want `f"{name_a}+site:sherdog.com"`.

Comment: Additionally, scraping Google's search results is against their Terms of Service, so don't be surprised if you suddenly get blocked.

Comment: Try using google's api instead. This is within Google's TOS, and you may be able to get google support too.